# Dropdown select with default value

Tags: javascript, d3.js

How do I set the option `selected` on load when creating multiple dropdowns?

When the page finishes loading, the first dropdown should have 'Horse' selected, the second dropdown should have 'Cow' selected, and the third dropdown should have 'Fox' selected.

```
  let widgetContainer = d3.select('#dropdowns')
  let animalNames = ["Horse", "Dog", "Cow", "Fox", "Cat", "Pig", "Aardvark", "Baboon", "Elephant"]
  let selectedNames = ["Horse", "Cow", "Fox"]
  let dropdowns = widgetContainer
    .selectAll(".widget-select")
    .data(selectedNames)
    .join("select")
    .attr("id", (d, idx) => `select-${idx}`)
    .attr("class", "animal-select")
    .on("change", (animalName, idx, selectElements) => {
      let selectedValues = selectElements.map((elem) => elem.value);
      // function that sets state for graph and renders
      onAnimalSelect(selectedValues);
    });

  let options = dropdowns
    .selectAll("option")
    .data(animalNames)
    .join("option")
    .property("selected", (opt) => {
      // how to find the parent node to set selected?
    })
    .attr("value", (opt) => opt)
    .text((opt) => opt);
```

Here's a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/denisemauldin/x0znphky/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the second and third parameters combined gives us the DOM element (`n[i]` in this example), and from that we can go up to its parent using `parentNode`. Therefore, it can be:

```
.property("selected", (opt, i, n) => d3.select(n[i].parentNode).datum() === opt)
```

Here is your code with that change:

```js
let widgetContainer = d3.select('#dropdowns')
let animalNames = ["Horse", "Dog", "Cow", "Fox", "Cat", "Pig", "Aardvark", "Baboon", "Elephant"]
let selectedNames = ["Horse", "Cow", "Fox"]
let dropdowns = widgetContainer
  .selectAll(".widget-select")
  .data(selectedNames)
  .join("select")
  .attr("id", (d, idx) => `select-${idx}`)
  .attr("class", "animal-select")
  .on("change", (animalName, idx, selectElements) => {
    let selectedValues = selectElements.map((elem) => elem.value);
    // function that sets state for graph and renders
    onAnimalSelect(selectedValues);
  });

let options = dropdowns
  .selectAll("option")
  .data(animalNames)
  .join("option")
  .property("selected", (opt, i, n) => d3.select(n[i].parentNode).datum() === opt)
  .attr("value", (opt) => opt)
  .text((opt) => opt);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.4.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<p>
  Here are some dropdowns. How do we set the default value on load?
</p>
<div id="dropdowns">
</div>
```

Comment: What is .datum() here? And is node (n) the option and parentNode the select? Thanks